# SOLR WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Tags: search, solr, numeric

I use WordDelimiterFilterFactory to split words that have numbers into solr tokens. For example the word Php5 is split in two tokens **"PHP"**, **"5"**.When searching, the request that is executed by SOLR is q="php" and q="5". But this request finds even results with **"5"** only. What I want is to find documents with **"PHP5"** or **"PHP 5"** only.

If someone has any idea to get around this please.

Hope it is clear.

Thank's.

Comment: <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/> mark generateNumberParts="0". This will not split the words..

Comment: ok I'm gonna try with this configuration. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get solr, in addition to indexing "php5", to index "php 5" as a single token.  That way a search for "php 5" will match but a search for "blah 5" will not, for example.

The only way I was able to get this to work well was to use the [Auto Phrasing filter by lucid work](https://github.com/LucidWorks/auto-phrase-tokenfilter)s.

```
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
        <filter class="com.lucidworks.analysis.AutoPhrasingTokenFilterFactory" phrases="autophrases.txt" includeTokens="true" replaceWhitespaceWith="_" />  
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

synonyms.txt

```
php5,php_5
```

protwords.txt (so the delimiter doesn't break it)

```
php5,php_5
```

You also have to change the query parser to use the lucid parser.

solrconfig.xml

```
<queryParser name="autophrasingParser" class="com.lucidworks.analysis.AutoPhrasingQParserPlugin" >
  <str name="phrases">autophrases.txt</str>
  <str name="replaceWhitespaceWith">_</str>
  <str name="ignoreCase">false</str>
</queryParser> 
<requestHandler name="/searchp" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
         <int name="rows">10</int>
         <str name="df">Keywords</str>
         <str name="defType">autophrasingParser</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

autophrases.txt

```
php 5
```

The filter can be found here: https://github.com/LucidWorks/auto-phrase-tokenfilter

This article was also very helpful: http://lucidworks.com/2014/07/02/automatic-phrase-tokenization-improving-lucene-search-precision-by-more-precise-linguistic-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

This filter splits tokens at word delimiters.

In your case you can opt for `splitOnNumerics="0"`, so it wont spilt on numbers.

> `splitOnNumerics`:
>
> (integer, default 1) If 0, don't split words on
> transitions from alpha to numeric:"FemBot3000" -> "Fem", "Bot3000"

The rules for determining delimiters are determined in the below link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter